# CC2541 IAR Output

Tags: c, embedded, iar, texas-instruments

To begin, I am working on [CC2541](http://www.ti.com/product/cc2541) [IAR](http://www.iar.com/) [8.20 for 8051](http://www.iar.com/Products/Wireless-solutions/Tools-for-TI-wireless/).
I would like to write in output or file for check the communication between my application and the device.

Even if I have the [CC-Debugger](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc-debugger) and I know if I do `View -> Messages -> Tool Output`, its output open but how I can write in this window ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found.

I post the answer whether other people need it.
You can use :

```
puts(const char *);
putchar(int);
getchar(void);
sprintf(char *,const char *,...);
vsprintf(char *,const char *,va_list);
printf(const char *,...);
vprintf(const char *,va_list);
```

([source](http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/63128#pi239031349=1))

After that, run the Debug mode.
When you are in debug mode :

View -> Terminal I/O

([source](http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/p/262360/922267#922267))

Comment: Does this require an RS232 connection to the cc2541 or does it use the CC-Debugger for output to IAR?

Comment: I use the CC-Debugger to show execution and messages is in the window Output by IAR.